# Django says port is already in use

Tags: django

When I run the Django `runserver` command it shows port is already in use. So every time I need to kill the process that uses the port and run the server again.

Can anyone give me a permanent solution to this?

Comment: Of course you need to kill the old server before starting it again; only one process can bind to any given port at once. Are you running `manage.py runserver` multiple times? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another port, coz may be the `port` you are using have some problem.

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

and yes, you need to kill the previous running server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other processes running you should always kill them before trying to run another process on the same port.

I use the following **Terminal** command:

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

This will kill the process on the specified port.

You can also run the Django development server on other ports assuming they are not already in use by another programme.

```
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you use CTRL+Z instead of CTRL+C.

```
CTRL+Z ->  Suspend process
CTRL+C ->  Stop process
```

There are many recommendations around StackOverflow.
I would like to recommend the best way from my perspective(You simply need to remember two commands).

Firstly see the jobs in the background by simply typing **`jobs`** in the terminal.

[This is what shows up after you type job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NHNf.png)

You can see the job number as 4, 5, and 6.
So If I want to kill the process for job 6 which is python manage.py runserver. I simply can type **`kill %6`**

[Killing job no 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RksIE.png)

Though sometimes CTRL+C doesn't kill the process. And if above doesn't work well you can use this command:

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
```

if you face any other issue , click this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213044/17497683

Answer (score 0):

more than one Terminal may be opened and running at the same time