# Django/Python - Error: That port is already in use

Tags: python, django, port, host, netstat

I'm trying to host my Django website for the first time, but it appears that the port is already in use. I haven't hosted anything before and I get the following result with netstat -ntlp:

[image]

I would like to keep the standard port if possible... does anyone know a solution?
I'm not sudo user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django says port is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025002/django-says-port-is-already-in-use)

Comment: I post an answer but I realize you wnat to keep the standard port. Why is that?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears that I need to use another port after all. Thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't kill the process because you don't have permissions, just serve django in a different port:

```
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

Comment: This will just add a new port. It doesn't solve the real problem.

Answer (score 8):

You need to kill the process which is running on port 8000.To kill, find out the process identifier number or PID of the process to be killed, then pass the PID number to the kill command. 
For Mac OS/X you can list the process by:`lsof -i:8000`

And then kill the PID by: `kill -9 PID`

Comment: I'm not root so I can't find the PID of processes, as you can see from the netstat screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

open your **Terminal** and try this,

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes there may be another server is running under that port in your machine
or
Use

```
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

Note: You can user any port